# jQuery QuickFit - works only with one element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

i use this plugin https://github.com/chunksnbits/jquery-quickfit

i have many elements on page like this:

```
<div id="quickfit-a">........</div>
<div id="quickfit-a">........</div>
...
<div id="quickfit-a">........</div>
```

and this Javascript like on demo:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(function() {
    $(window).on('resize', function() {
      $('#quickfit-a').quickfit({ max: 40, min: 20, truncate: true });        

    });
    $(window).trigger('resize');    
  });
</script>
```

but this Javascript code works only for the first element with id = quickfit-a

how to make that function works for all elements on the page with id = quickfit-a

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Rather than id you can try with a class attribute as below

```
<div class="quickfit-a">........</div>
<div class="quickfit-a">........</div>
...
<div class="quickfit-a">........</div>
```

and change your demo as

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(function() {
    $(window).on('resize', function() {
      $('.quickfit-a').quickfit({ max: 40, min: 20, truncate: true });        

    });
    $(window).trigger('resize');    
  });
</script>
```